# remove table rows with modifying data

Tags: javascript, jquery

A form has table with many rows. User can click a button to delete a row.

```
        <tr class="fes-single-variation">
            <td class="fes-name-row">
                <input class="fes-name-value" name="option[0][description]" id="options[0][description]" rows="3" value="" type="text">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="fes-single-variation">
            <td class="fes-name-row">
                <input class="fes-name-value" name="option[1][description]" id="options[1][description]" rows="3" value="" type="text">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="fes-single-variation">
            <td class="fes-name-row">
                <input class="fes-name-value" name="option[2][description]" id="options[2][description]" rows="3" value="" type="text">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="fes-single-variation">
            <td class="fes-name-row">
                <input class="fes-name-value" name="option[3][description]" id="options[3][description]" rows="3" value="" type="text">
            </td>
        </tr>
```

Lets say user wants to remove 2nd row

```
        <tr class="fes-single-variation">
            <td class="fes-name-row">
                <input class="fes-name-value" name="option[1][description]" id="options[1][description]" rows="3" value="" type="text">
            </td>
        </tr>
```

and then user submits the form so that many values need to be update before the form is submitted, such as:

`name="option[2][description]` should be `name="option[1][description]`

`name="option[3][description]` should be `name="option[2][description]`

how can i use jQuery to manage those update?
does jQuery has some kind of build-in functions to handle this?

thanks

Comment: **option[n][description]**, is the **n** is user defined? If not use **option[][description]**

Comment: n is user defined (plugin's author defined it) and i cant remove it.

Comment: No build in functionality to change the name, use regex to change the input name.If you need the full code then i will post here.

Comment: thanks for that. Yes, if you could kindly show me the code so that i can learn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood your question, I think this is what you're asking about :

[**JS Fiddle**-*updated*](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/1cn5mLqt/) << *forgot the closing square bracket in* `att`, *fixed now*

```js
$('.btn').on('click', function(){
    // On each button click event we delete the parent tr
    // then we call a function to update the input fields
    $(this).parents('tr').remove();
    updateRows();
});

function updateRows(){
    // here we select all inputs text fields in tr which 
    // have .fes-single-variation class and update their
    // name and id attributes according to the index value
    $('tr.fes-single-variation td input[type="text"]').each(function(index){
        var att = 'option[' +index+ '][description]';
        $(this).attr('id',att).attr('name', att);
      
        //the below line is just for demo purpose
        //not part of solution
        $(this).val('option['+index+']');
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="fes-single-variation">
    <td class="fes-name-row">
      <input class="fes-name-value" name="option[0][description]" id="options[0][description]" rows="3" value="option[0]" type="text">
    </td>
    <td>
      <button class="btn">Delete</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="fes-single-variation">
    <td class="fes-name-row">
      <input class="fes-name-value" name="option[1][description]" id="options[1][description]" rows="3" value="option[1]" type="text">
    </td>
    <td>
      <button class="btn">Delete</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="fes-single-variation">
    <td class="fes-name-row">
      <input class="fes-name-value" name="option[2][description]" id="options[2][description]" rows="3" value="option[2]" type="text">
    </td>
    <td>
      <button class="btn">Delete</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="fes-single-variation">
    <td class="fes-name-row">
      <input class="fes-name-value" name="option[3][description]" id="options[3][description]" rows="3" value="option[3]" type="text">
    </td>
    <td>
      <button class="btn">Delete</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```